# I have no error showing up in my code but when my program reaches the "chooseCard" function it terminates

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to let the player choose what cards they want to keep from their hand of 5 cards. I am trying to do this in my chooseCards function but when the user chooses to replace a card it terminates with no error.

I have tried changing the types of pointers in the function hoping that was the issue but nothing changed. When the user enters "n" (to replace a card) the program quits. However, the passCard function works flawlessly earlier in the program along with the shuffle function, so I am confused on where the issue is. I know this would be far easier using arrays but the assignment requires linked lists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


typedef struct card_s {
    char suit[20];
    int face;
    struct card_s *next;
}card;


void makeDeck(card** currentCard) {
    int i, j;
    char cardsuit[20];
    card *tempCard = '-', *tail = NULL, *lastcard = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < 13; i += 1) {   // 13 cards per suit

        for (j = 0; j < 4; j += 1) {    // 4 suits
            tempCard = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
            if (j == 0) {
                strcpy(cardsuit, "of diamonds");
            }
            else if (j == 1) {
                strcpy(cardsuit, "of hearts");
            }
            else if (j == 2) {
                strcpy(cardsuit, "of clubs");
            }
            else if (j == 3) {
                strcpy(cardsuit, "of spades");
            }

            tempCard->face = i + 1;

            strcpy(tempCard->suit, cardsuit);


            tempCard->next = NULL;

            lastcard = tempCard;

            if (*currentCard == NULL) {

                *currentCard = tempCard;

            }

            else {

                tail->next = tempCard;

            }

            tail = tempCard;

            tail->next = NULL;  //sets final card place in list to null

        }
    }

    return;
}

int FindLength(card* currentcard) {
    int i = 0;
    while (currentcard != NULL) {
        i += 1; //increment i evry time current card has value
        currentcard = currentcard->next;
    }
    return i;
}

void shuffleDeck(card** currentCard, int deckLength) {

    int cardcount, place, i, rng;
    int j = 0;

    card *shuffled = NULL;
    card *unshuffled = NULL;
    card *tempCard = NULL;


    srand(time(NULL));


    for (place = 0; place < deckLength; place += 1) {

        shuffled = *currentCard;
        unshuffled = *currentCard;


        tempCard = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));

        rng = rand() % deckLength;

        for (cardcount = 0; cardcount < rng; cardcount += 1) {
            unshuffled = unshuffled->next;
        }
        for (cardcount = 0; cardcount < place; cardcount += 1) {
            shuffled = shuffled->next;
        }

        strcpy(tempCard->suit, unshuffled->suit);   //swap the suits of each card
        strcpy(unshuffled->suit, shuffled->suit);
        strcpy(shuffled->suit, tempCard->suit);

        tempCard->face = unshuffled->face;      //swap value of the cards
        unshuffled->face = shuffled->face;
        shuffled->face = tempCard->face;

    }

    return;
}

void pushFront(card** head, char* suit, int face) {

    card* temp = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));

    temp->face = face;
    strcpy(temp->suit, suit);
    temp->next = *head;

    *head = temp;   //new card put at head of list
}

void removeFront(card **head) {

    card* temp = NULL;

    temp = *head;       //point temp to first card

    *head = (*head)->next;      //set head to the next card

    free(temp);     //free the first 

}

void passCard(card** giver, card** taker) {

    pushFront(taker, (*giver)->suit, (*giver)->face);
    removeFront(giver);

    return;
}

void dealCards(card** deck, card** p1, card** p2) {

    card* current = NULL;

    current = *deck;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            passCard(deck, p1);
        }
        else {
            passCard(deck, p2);
        }

    }
    return;
}

void chooseCards(card*hand, card*deck) {

    int i, chosenCard = 0;
    char answer;

    for (i = 1; i < 6; i += 1) {


        printf("Keep card %d? (y or n): ", i);
        scanf(" %c", &answer);

        if (answer == 'n') {
            passCard(hand, deck);
            shuffleDeck(deck, FindLength(deck));
            passCard(deck, hand);
        }
        hand = hand->next;

    }

    return;
}

int main() {
    card *cards = NULL;         //deck of cards
    card *player1 = NULL;       //p1 hand
    card *dealer = NULL;        //dealer hand

    makeDeck(&cards);   //create deck of 52 cards

    int deckLength = Findlength(cards);
    shuffleDeck(&cards, deckLength);    //shuffle deck of cards

    dealCards(&cards, &player1, &dealer);   //deal to player 1 and dealer

    //print player 1 hand

    chooseCards(&player1, &cards);

    //print player 1 hand, chosen cards have been replaced by cards in the deck

    return 0;
}
```

The output is supposed to replace the chosen card with a card from the deck.

Comment: Need `player` declarations.

Comment: what is `shuffleDeck` ??

Comment: Please provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Without that, we really can't help you.

Comment: *when my program reaches the "chooseCard" function it terminates* This *is* an error showing up in your code. A run-time error. Use a debugger to isolate and fix it.

Comment: I added more to the code to give you guys a better picture I hope it helps

Comment: `card *tempCard = '-'` This is meaningless and [should not compile](https://ideone.com/mzSfAY). There are more instances of bad handling of pointers. Are you ignoring compiler warnings by any chance? You should treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: Didn't you already post [this exact code to shuffle a deck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55895160/issue-with-shuffling-deck) and didn't I point out your memory leak? It's still there.

Comment: Seriously, your code cannot even compile.

Answer (score 0):

When I compile your code I get:

```
joshua@nova:/tmpϟ gcc testshuffle.c
testshuffle.c: In function ‘makeDeck’:
testshuffle.c:18:22: warning: initialization of ‘card *’ {aka ‘struct card_s *’} from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     card *tempCard = '-', *tail = NULL, *lastcard = NULL;
                      ^~~
testshuffle.c: In function ‘chooseCards’:
testshuffle.c:182:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘passCard’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             passCard(hand, deck);
                      ^~~~
testshuffle.c:143:22: note: expected ‘card **’ {aka ‘struct card_s **’} but argument is of type ‘card *’ {aka ‘struct card_s *’}
 void passCard(card** giver, card** taker) {
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~
testshuffle.c:182:28: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘passCard’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             passCard(hand, deck);
                            ^~~~
testshuffle.c:143:36: note: expected ‘card **’ {aka ‘struct card_s **’} but argument is of type ‘card *’ {aka ‘struct card_s *’}
 void passCard(card** giver, card** taker) {
                         ~~~~~~~^~~~~
testshuffle.c:183:25: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘shuffleDeck’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             shuffleDeck(deck, FindLength(deck));
                         ^~~~
testshuffle.c:77:25: note: expected ‘card **’ {aka ‘struct card_s **’} but argument is of type ‘card *’ {aka ‘struct card_s *’}
 void shuffleDeck(card** currentCard, int deckLength) {
                  ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
testshuffle.c:184:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘passCard’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         passCard(deck, hand);
                  ^~~~
testshuffle.c:143:22: note: expected ‘card **’ {aka ‘struct card_s **’} but argument is of type ‘card *’ {aka ‘struct card_s *’}
 void passCard(card** giver, card** taker) {
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~
testshuffle.c:184:28: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘passCard’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             passCard(deck, hand);
                            ^~~~
testshuffle.c:143:36: note: expected ‘card **’ {aka ‘struct card_s **’} but argument is of type ‘card *’ {aka ‘struct card_s *’}
 void passCard(card** giver, card** taker) {
                         ~~~~~~~^~~~~
testshuffle.c: In function ‘main’:
testshuffle.c:207:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘chooseCards’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     chooseCards(&player1, &cards);
                 ^~~~~~~~
testshuffle.c:170:23: note: expected ‘card *’ {aka ‘struct card_s *’} but argument is of type ‘card **’ {aka ‘struct card_s **’}
 void chooseCards(card*hand, card*deck) {
                  ~~~~~^~~~
testshuffle.c:207:27: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘chooseCards’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     chooseCards(&player1, &cards);
                           ^~~~~~
testshuffle.c:170:34: note: expected ‘card *’ {aka ‘struct card_s *’} but argument is of type ‘card **’ {aka ‘struct card_s **’}
 void chooseCards(card*hand, card*deck) {
                             ~~~~~^~~~
```

When I run it I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555530d in FindLength ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000055555555530d in FindLength ()
#1  0x0000555555555618 in chooseCards ()
#2  0x00005555555556ce in main ()
(gdb)
```

Fix all your warnings. You will find your problem therein. You have bad type conversions between `card*` and `card**` that's causing `FindLength` to crash. In particular, `FindLength` wants a `card*` but got passed a `card**` in a variable declared to contain `card*` from `chooseCards()` and proceed to interpret the middle of the suit string as the next pointer and crash accessing unallocated memory.